# How to get .nodeType property to display 2?

Tags: javascript, dom, document, nodes

HTML

```
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
```

JavaScript

```
var element = document.getElementById("title");

console.log(element.nodeType);  // 1
console.log(element.id.nodeType); // undefined
console.log(element.firstChild.nodeType); // 3
```

I want to retrieve the attribute nodeType, why do I get `undefined`? 
Also, is there a better way to retrieve the textNode, not using firstChild, but something else?

Comment: @crush I tried this, but it gives me a undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In the DOM, [Node type 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) is reserved for attributes. You can inspect these nodes using the `attributes` property of the parent node.

```
console.log(element.attributes[0].nodeType);  // 2
```

Comment: +1 I did not know that attributes were based on arrays!

Comment: @crush that just get's the value, but I wanted the nodeType of 2

Comment: @kozlovski5 the `attributes` property is not actually an array, but a a [`NamedNodeMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap)

Comment: Isn't everything in the `attributes` `NamedNodeMap` going to be nodeType 2?

Answer (score -1):

`element.id` contains a value that is a string.  That string does not have a `nodeType`.

Perhaps if you explain what problem you're really trying to solve, we could help explain why you're confused and trying to obtain a `nodeType` on a string.

The text node is a child object of the element.  If you know there is only one text node, then `element.firstChild` is a way to retrieve it.  If you want all text in the object (not the actual text nodes), then you could use `element.textContent` (or `element.innerText` in older versions of IE).

You often have to be careful with text nodes because some browsers (yea, I'm pointing at you IE) will put a carriage return in a text node all by itself and there may end up being more text nodes than you expect just based on how the HTML was formatted (though it makes no difference in the display).  For that reason, it isn't the most robust code to just assume that the `Title` text is in the `element.firstChild`.  That's where `element.textContent` would be much easier and robust if you just need to text, not the actual text node.

Here's a simple cross-browser function that will get you the element's text:

```
function getElementText(el) {
   if (typeof el.textContent !== "undefined") {
       return el.textContent;
   }
   return el.innerText;
}
```

Or, if you want the first child text node that has something in it other than whitespace:

```
function getFirstTextNode(el) {
    var child = el.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, "") !== "") {
            return child;
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  The is an entirely correct answer to why they are getting `undefined`.  If the OP explains what they're actually trying to do rather than making us try to guess, then we could be even more helpful.

Comment: Added info on the second part of the question - retrieving the text node.